# Bool condition checks gives warning

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve a problem here https://leetcode.com/problems/word-break/ . My code looks like below:-

```
bool existsInDict(string s, vector<string>& wordDict)
{
    if(std::find(wordDict.begin(),wordDict.end(),s) != wordDict.end())
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

class Solution {
public:
    bool wordBreak(string s, vector<string>& wordDict) {
        int str_size = s.length();
        if(str_size == 0)
        return true;

        bool *dict = new bool[str_size+1];
        std::fill(dict, dict+str_size,false);

        for(int i =1;i<=str_size;++i)
        {
            if(dict[i]==false && existsInDict(s.substr(0,i),wordDict))
            {
                dict[i] = true;
            }
            if(dict[i]==true)
            {
                if(i==str_size)
                return true;
                for(int j=i+1;j<=str_size;++j)
                {
                    if((dict[j]==false) && existsInDict(s.substr(i+1,j-i),wordDict))
                    {
                        dict[j] = true;
                    }
                    if((dict[j]==true) && (j == str_size))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

This gives me a error `Line 40: Char 25: runtime error: load of value 190, which is not a valid value for type 'bool' (solution.cpp) SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior prog_joined.cpp:49:25`

I am not sure what is wrong here as both my checks in the if loop on that line have a bool outcome. Can someone help me understand it ?

Thanks

Comment: `str_size+1` and `for(int i =1;i<=str_size;++i)` is not the correct way. Array indexes are zero-based, not one-based. Stop being part of a [cargo cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) and invest in [some good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to learn C++ properly. Oh, and stop using sites like that to learn the basics of programming or languages, that's just not their purpose.

Comment: Thanks looks like i figured out the issue by the way which is std::fill(dict, dict+str_size,false); should have std::fill(dict, dict+str_size+1,false); Agree with your thoughts but sometimes starting with 1 gives more clarity in some cases while composing the algo.

Comment: Why a dynamic array in the first place? `std::vector<bool> dict(str_size+1, false);` will also work, and you cannot forget to `delete[]` it at the end.

Comment: @BoP Vector is also a heap allocation in general. Yes, agree with delete thing.

Answer (score 1):

you are checking if `dict[j]` is `true` and if `j` is equal to `str_size`, however,the problem occurs when `j` becomes equal to `str_size`, so I think you must modify the loop condition to `j < str_size` instead of `j <= str_size` because it ensures you the `j` remains within the bounds of the `dict` array!

so fix it like below :

```
if ((dict[j] == true) && (j == str_size - 1))
```